# How do I prevent EntityDataSource to execute a query if controlparameters are invalid?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, validation, entitydatasource

On an ASP.NET web page I have an EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceOrders" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=EntitiesContext"
        DefaultContainerName="EntitiesContext" 
        EntitySetName="Order" 
        Select="it.OrderID,it.OrderCode,it.OrderDateTime"
        Where="it.OrderDateTime &gt;= @DateTimeFrom AND it.OrderDateTime &lt;= @DateTimeTo"
        OrderBy="it.SOrderCode"
        StoreOriginalValuesInViewState="False" >
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="DateTimeFrom" 
                                  ControlID="TextBoxDateTimeFrom"
                                  DbType="DateTime"
                                  PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="DateTimeTo"
                                  ControlID="TextBoxDateTimeTo"
                                  DbType="DateTime"
                                  PropertyName="Text" />
        </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

As you can see there are two Textboxes on the page to enter an earliest and latest date for my selection. These Textboxes are used as ControlParameters in Where-clause of the EntityDataSource.

Now imagine someone enters an invalid date like "32/01/2010" in one of those ControlParameter textboxes.

I am aware that I can validate at first on client side (using the ASP.NET validators), so I prevent a postback if the input is invalid.

But how do I implement the more important "final" validation on server side? Especially WHERE (which method or event) do I implement it to prevent the EntityDataSource to execute the query with invalid DateTime values in the Textboxes?

Basically my idea was to call something like `Page.Validate()` and then `Page.IsValid` and, if IsValid returns false, to "cancel" the EntityDataSource query execution (or prevent it to start at all). But I don't know where or in which event I can hook up into the EntityDataSource to prevent the query execution.

Perhaps I am thinking into the wrong direction. Does somebody have an idea what to do?

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the responsibility of the EntityDataSource to check for validity. When you have a 'save' button on the page, the code behind the button click can check for `Page.IsValid`. When you are working with standard ASP.NET controls, such as the GridView, those controls will call `Page.IsValid` for you.

So in your situation, I'd go with ASP.NET validation controls on the page. They will also run on the server side.

**[Update]**

You can hook-up a method to the `EntityDataSource.Selecting` event and set the `Cancel` property of the `EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs` to true when the page is not valid.

```
private void EntityDataSourceOrders_Selecting(
    object sender, EntityDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !this.Page.IsValid;
}
```

Comment: @Steven: I understand your proposal. But my problem is that I don't know what to do if the validation fails. For example: In the ButtonClick event you mentioned I check `Page.IsValid` and it returns false. What now? I want to tell now the EntityDataSource NOT to run a query with those invalid dates. (Instead the user shall correct the dates at first.) The only way I can think of at the moment is to clear the TextBoxes. Otherwise if I don't do this, the ControlParameter collection of the EntityDataSource "automatically" pulls the invalid dates from the TextBoxes and throws an exception.

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I was looking for! And so easy, embarrassing that I didn't see that event. Thank you very much!